# Need some help figuring out compile-time error: 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "boost::system::system_category()"'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unix, boost

I've been trying to get the `boost` library into the C++ program I'm making in XCode 6.0 and the instructions I've been following are [these ones](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). The library I need is `filesystem` and I'm aware that I need to build that one separately. But I'm a little confused as to what that means. I downloaded `boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2`, unpacked it and followed the instructions in 5.1. Then I set the Header Search Paths in XCode to the path of `boost_1_57_0`, added #include `<boost/filesystem.hpp>` to my program and tried to compile. The error I got was

**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what I've done wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Technically that's not a *compiler* error, it's a *linker* error. And the error is because the linker can't find those symbols, because you need to link with the `boost_system` library.

Comment: And don't forget `-lboost_filesystem` in case that's next up