# How to "link with the boost_system library" in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker

[Yesterday I asked a question about how to get the Boost library into my C++ program in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346134/need-some-help-figuring-out-compile-time-error-undefined-symbols-for-architect?noredirect=1#comment45036503_28346134) and I was told I need to link to the boost_system library. I tried to figure out how to do that, but am not sure how. I tried to follow the instructions as best as possible and here are what my Linking configurations look like:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/1zh2lq0.jpg

That is obviously not correct because I get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_system
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I try to compile. My header search paths are, apparently, correct, since I have #include `<boost/filesystem.hpp>` and the compiler is finding that file. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: maybe like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14153027/1810087)

Comment: where do you have boost installed?